# How to Test a StateNotifiers reaction to a Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, freezed

## My Setup

I have a StateNotifier whose state is a @freezed class:

```dart
@freezed
class MyFreezedState with _$MyFreezedState{
  const factory MyFreezedState({
    required AsyncValue<int> asyncFreezedStateInt,
  }) = MyFreezedState;
}
```

```dart
class MyStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<MyFreezedState>{
    const MyStateNotifier(MyFreezedState state) : super(state);
}
```

Inside the StateNotifier I want to listen to a stream, and set the state's data accordingly, so my final setup looks like this :

```dart
final myStateNotifierProvider = Provider<MyStateNotifier, MyFreezedState>((ref) {
    final intStream = ref.watch(myIntStreamProvider);
    
    return MyStateNotifier(
     MyFreezedState(
       asyncFreezedStateInt: AsyncValue.loading(),
     ),
     asyncIntStreamValue : intStream
    );
});

class MyStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<MyFreezedState>{
    MyStateNotifier (
      MyFreezedState state, {
      required this.asyncIntStreamValue,
    }) : super(state) {
      reactToIntStreamChanges();
    }

    final AsyncValue<int> asyncIntStreamValue;

    void reactToIntStreamChanges(){
      asyncIntStreamValue.when(
       data: (intData) { 
         state = state.copyWith(asyncFreezedStateInt : AsyncValue.data(intData);
       },
       error: (err, stk) { 
         state = state.copyWith(asyncFreezedStateInt : AsyncValue.error(err,stk); 
       },
       loading () {
         state = state.copyWith(asyncFreezedStateInt : AsyncValue.loading();
       }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected until here.

## The Problem

The problem here is, that I don't know how to properly test the reaction to the stream.

This is my test setup:

```dart
void main() {
  late ProviderContainer container;
  late MockIntService mockIntService;

  setUp((){
    mockIntService = MockIntService();
    container = ProviderContainer(
      overrides: [myIntServiceProvider.overrideWithValue(mockIntService)],
    );
    when(() => mockIntService.myIntStream).thenAnswer((invocation) {
      return Stream<int>.fromIterable([1]);
    });
  })
```

### What I have tried

#### Doesn't work

```dart
  //This test fails, the value is still an AsyncValue.loading()
  test('should set the states value if stream emits value',(){
     final stateValue = container.read(myStateNotifierProvider).asyncFreezedStateInt;
     expect(stateValue, AsyncValue.data(1));
  });
```

#### Works but is hacky and ugly

After doing some research I came up with this solution but I feel like there has to be a better way.

```dart
  //This test passes, but I feel like this is a bad approach.
  test('should set the states value if stream emits value',(){
     fakeAsync((async){
        container.read(myStateNotifierProvider);
        async.elapse(const Duration(milliseconds:100);
        final stateValue = 
           container.read(myStateControllerProvider).asyncFreezedStateInt;
       expect(stateValue, AsyncValue.data(1));
     });
  });
}
```

## EDIT

This is the condensed version of the service where the stream comes from :

```dart
final myIntStreamProvider = StreamProvider((ref) {
  return ref.read(intServiceProvider).intStream;
});

final intServiceProvider = Provider<BaseTemplateService>((ref) {
  return IntService();
});

class IntService {
  Stream<Int> get intStream => firestore
          .collection("intValues")
          .snapshots();
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what is MockIntService?

Comment: It is the mocked service that returns the stream (myIntStream). I am watching the "live" version of this stream in the `myStateNotifierProvider`

Comment: I see, could you add its code to the question ,please

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have added a condensed version of the service to the question. 

I have also updated the ref.watch(myIntService).intStream to ref.watch(myIntStreamProvider) in the StateNotifier section to reflect the changes

Answer (score 0):

The firsts `container.read()` return always loading, because the `container.watch()` cannot be implemented.

I think it's cleaner this way:

```
test('should set the states value if stream emits value', () async {
  var stateValue = container.read(myStateNotifierProvider);

  expect(stateValue, const MyFreezedState.loading());
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

  stateValue = container.read(myStateNotifierProvider);
  expect(stateValue, const MyFreezedState.data(AsyncValue.data(1)));
});
```

State:

```
@freezed
abstract class MyFreezedState with _$MyFreezedState {
  const factory MyFreezedState.loading() = _Loading;
  const factory MyFreezedState.data(AsyncValue<int> asyncValue) = _Data;
  const factory MyFreezedState.error() = _Error;
}
```

I hope it's help you!